# select duplicate rows based on another column value in R

Tags: r

How do I select duplicated rows which belong to the same ID based on a specific value in another column i.e. Activity C?

This is the original dataframe

```
ID  Activity  Cost 
1       A       8
1       B       2
1       C       5
2       A       4
3       A       2
3       C       7
3       C       1
4       A       3
4       B       8
```

This is the targeted dataframe i.e. only ID 1 and ID 3 are selected as they contain Activity C

```
ID  Activity  Cost 
    1       A       8
    1       B       2
    1       C       5
    3       A       2
    3       C       7
    3       C       1
```

On the flip side, how do I get a dataframe where the ID do not have Activity C?
Flipside data frame:

```
   ID  Activity   Cost 
    2       A       4
    4       A       3
    4       B       8
```

Cheers

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter('C' %in% Activity)`  For the second case `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!'C' %in% Activity)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Initially I used `Activity == "C"` which resulted in the lost of the other duplicated ID rows. Where else  can I learn more about `%in%`?